# Get source of a website which requires post login

Tags: html, parsing, shell, scripting, http-post

I wan't to write a script to get the source of a website which requires a post login. 
I need a shell script to do this. I want to parse some information. 
Any idea which language is the best choice for handling the http request and maybe cookies?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with shell programming, [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) can do a POST to get you the source of a web page. -- See the -d option.

You can then use shell scripting with grep, sed or other options to parse the results.

More automated/sophisticated/complicated is to write a web scraper program using Perl, Ruby, pick-your-language

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Never used it from the command line myself, but it's able to send POST variables.